# How to fix z-index issue that does not work despite already having position & higher z-index value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement z-index change on hover but it doesn't seem to work despite already using "position" on my elements.

This is what I was trying to do (the red navigation right or left side should go under the poster element on hover using z-index):

[image]

**But this is what happen instead (z-index not working)**:
[image]

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  stagePadding: 50,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  overflow: visible;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  height: 9%;
  width: auto;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.owl-nav button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: red;
  background: rgb(255 1 1 / 40%)!important;
  display: block;
  margin: 0!important;
}

.owl-nav button span {
  color: white!important;
  font-size: 51px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyp13K1.jpg"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

**As you can see on the right side**, despite already using position & z index on the poster element higher than the navigation element (the red ones), the poster element still sits underneath the navigation element.

How to fix this z-index issue?

Comment: your requirement is tricky with the OWL implementation, is it okay for you if both the arrows go behind the posters, or you exactly needed what you shown in SS.

Comment: How would a user access the controls if they're behind the image? There's a reason that those are positioned absolutely and laid over the slider.

Comment: its only for hover effect @isherwood

Comment: Yes. I know this. My point stands.

Comment: Right, user will never be able to go next.

Comment: @AtulRajput hello, I only needed both or any of the arrows/navigations to go behind the poster that is being hovered so the other non-hovered item still sits behind it.

Comment: @isherwood hello, The users would still be able to click on the next button because on the actual site, the navigation element's width are much wider so the next/navigation element is not entirely covered.